# is there a 2D dictionary in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I was about to create a matrix like :

```
    33  12  23  42  11  32  43  22
33  −   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
12  1   −   1   1   0   0   1   1
23  1   1   −   1   1   1   0   0
42  1   1   1   −   1   1   0   0
11  0   0   1   1   −   1   1   1
32  0   0   1   1   1   −   1   1
43  1   1   0   0   1   1   −   1
22  1   1   0   0   1   1   1   −
```

I want to query by horizontal or vertical titles, so I created the matrix by：

```
a = np.matrix('99 33    12  23  42  11  32  43 22;33    99  1   1   1   0   0   1   1;12    1   99  1   1   0   0   1   1;23    1   1   99  1   1   1   0   0;42    1   1   1   99  1   1   0   0;11    0   0   1   1   99  1   1   1;32    0   0   1   1   1   99  1   1;43    1   1   0   0   1   1   99  1;22    1   1   0   0   1   1   1   99')
```

I want to have the certain data if I query a[23][11] = 1

so is there a way we can create a 2D dictionary, so that a[23][11] = 1?

Thanks

Comment: By 2D dictionary, you mean nested dictionary to one degree/depth?

Comment: You could use a `defaultdict(dict)`, or just write a `dict` with integer keys and `dict` values

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thank you so much for the reply! could you please give me an example that I can tell whether it is the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the numpy code you've shown relates to the question you're asking about dictionaries. numpy uses its own kind of syntax for multi-dimensional indexing. Are you just looking for `a[23,11]`?

Comment: @Blckknght thank you! the problem solved!

Comment: @Blckknght@Warren Weckesser thank you guys! I just applied nested dictionary for the problem, and it solved! thanks

Comment: can use `record arrays` for this too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're clearly asking for something outside of `numpy`.

A [`defauldict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) with the *`default_factory`* as `dict` gives a sense of the *2D dictionary* you want:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(dict)
>>> a[23][11] = 1
>>> a[23]
{11: 1}
>>> a[23][11]
1
```

Comment: Hey, may I ask what the format of "dict" should be?

Comment: @Condo_programmer How do you mean, want to give an example?

Comment: @Condo_programmer https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects

Comment: @Condo_programmer accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use tuples as the dictionary keys

```
dict((33,12):1, (23,12):1, ...]
```

`scipy.sparse` has a sparse matrix format that stores it's values in such a dictionary.  With your values such a matrix would represent a 50x50 matrix with mostly 0 values, and just 1's at these selected coordinates.

Keep in mind that the keys of a dictionary (ordinary at least) are not ordered

What are going to be doing with this data?  A dictionary, whether type or nested, is good for one kind of usage, but bad for others.  A matrix such as you sample is better for other things, like operations along rows or columns.  The dictionary format largely obscures that kind of ordered layout.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a dictionary with pairs as keys?

```
d = {}
d[33, 12] = 1
d[33, 23] = 1
# etc
```

Note that in python `d[a, b]` is just syntactic sugar for `d[(a, b)]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to label your row/columns. To stay within the numpy array framework, a simple solution would be to create a mapping between the labels and the array order. I am also going to assume that it is OK to convert the labels into strings as they can be anything (though integers would also be fine).

```
l = {str(x) : ind for ind , x in enumerate((33,12,23,42,11,32,43,22))}
a = sp.linalg.circulant([99,1,1,1,0,0,1,1])
a[l['32'],l['23']]
```